# Как выделить с помощью РВ Блок содержащий несколько строк?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выделить блок содержащий несколько строк целиком, в тексте имеющем вид:

```
заголовокБлока;
;строка
;строка
;строка

заголовокСледующегоБлока;
;строка
;строка
;строка
```

Если смотреть с символами разрыва строки, то выглядит текст так:

```
;строка предыдущего Блока\n
\n
заголовокБлока;\n
;строка\n
;строка\n
;строка\n
\n
заголовокСледующегоБлока;\n
;строка\n
;строка\n
;строка\n
\n
```

Делаю запрос `\n\n.+\n\n`, но он не срабатывает. Возможно ли как-то сформировать запрос что-бы выделялся один Блок целиком, не затрагивая другие блоки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось так:

```
 /(.|\s)*\n\n/gm
```

вот [ссылка](http://regexr.com/393nh) на движок где можно потестить.

Comment: Не срабатывает :( выделяет лишь последние строки блока, делаю поиск с помощью emEditor

Comment: А если так: /^((?:(?:\n|\r\n?).+)+)/gm

Comment: Выделяет только две строки, последовательно :/ Возможно мой редактор, как-то не так обрабатывает РВ, пока не получается на нем подобрать верное рабочее решение(

Comment: Установил notepad++ на нем все сработало как нужно! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Посмотрел emEditor чушь какая то... вот как миниммум надо юзать что-то из этого помимо notepad++, https://atom.io/ , http://www.sublimetext.com/

Comment: я emeditor использую как единственный, который может удалять дублирующие строки с выделенного без сортировки. не хотелось писать скрипт, но видимо придется, т.к. нотпад++ не умеет удалять дубли не сортируя(